# If $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^2<\infty $ then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. How do I prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^2<\infty$ then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence ?

Is the converse true?

How do I prove this?

For the converse, is $\{x_n\}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}$ working?

Comment: Converse is not true. $\{x_n\} = 1+ \frac{1}{x_n}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: if $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^2<\infty$ then $|x_n|^2\to 0$ and therefore $x_n\to 0$ and it is a Cauchy sequence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\vert x_n\vert^2<+\infty$, then $\lim \ \lvert x_n\rvert^2=0$, hence $\lim x_n=0$, so $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, hence it's a Cauchy sequence.

If $x_n=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n>0$ then $\{x_n\}$ is convergent to $0$, hence is a Cauchy sequence, but $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\lvert x_n\rvert^2=+\infty$ (it's the harmonic series). So the converse is false.

Comment: ....how to prove first part

Comment: How do I prove that its limit is $0$ or that it's a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @phiiippe Malot ..i mean that \sum ^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n|^2<\infty then how we prove the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is cauchy

Comment: Oh, that's easy. If a series is convergent, then its general term tends to $0$, in this case $\lvert x_n\rvert^2$ tends to $0$, hence $x_n$ tends to $0$. A convergent sequence is Cauchy.